# O que é e como resolver net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET?

Tags: php

Boa tarde,

Desenvolvi um sistema pare gerenciar o FTP da empresa onde trabalho, desta forma, localmente funciona perfeitamente e quando subo para o servidor e tento enviar um arquivo maior que 30mb, ele da falha no upload e retorna a seguinte mensagem no CONSOLE do navegador:

net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Pesquisei na internet e não consegui identificar a real causa desse problema.

Obrigado.

Comment: Concordo que é uma pergunta interessante, mas o problema raramente é de programação (só em casos muito específicos poderia ser), o que é indicado em nosso escopo, o problema geralmente é ocasionado por coisas além, como o uso de proxy, vpn, ou no momento do deploy algo falhou, também pode ser falha de configuração do servidor HTTP (como apache), pode ser também problema no firewall do computador cliente ou nas configurações de rede, não tem uma solução unica especifica e nem garantida para isso, esse erro é apenas um resumo de algo falhou. Obrigado por compreender.

Answer (score 5):

O Erro `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` informa que a conexão foi redefinda. Isso pode ocorrer por diversos motivos, como falha durante a conexão.

Tente acessar o seu sistema de uma conexão diferente, navegador e computador. Com isso é possivel eliminar a possibilidade de ser problema com sua maquina ou na sua rede, já que quando esta em servidor local funciona normalmente.
[Existe também a possibilidade de ser algum problema com firewall ou o provedor de internet](http://web.archive.org/web/20170104185439/http://blog.agmon.com/2013/07/05/solving-error-101-neterr_connection_reset-the-connection-was-reset/).

Segundo passo é verificar como esta configurado o servidor, verique se não existe algum limite de tamanho do upload, ou tempo máximo da conexão com servidor. Como você esta acessando o serviço com uma velocidade menor, é comum levar mais tempo e isso pode causar algum problema.